# Call one too from another in asdf

Tags: asdf

I'm running into a situation where one tool needs to spawn a child_process using another tool.

For example, my `.tool-versions` file looks like this:

```
java adoptopenjdk-21.0.0+35.0.LTS
nodejs 20.11.0
```

Both `node --version` and `java --version` work as expected. However, when I run the following js script:

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

spawn("java", [], {
  env: {
    PATH: process.env.PATH,
  },
  stdio: "inherit",
)
```

It prints

```
unknown command: java. Perhaps you have to reshim?
```

Can one tool call another tool like this?